# How to know if the current browser is loaded with C# code

Tags: c#

I am working with the Image generation of a browser, but doing so i am taking a snapshot of the browser from the code, in windows form. But if the browser is not loaded in the specific time (suppose 15 seconds) then a blank snapshot occur. Anyone help me with this .

Comment: You mean to say that you got a browser-element inside a winform, and want to know when it is done loading the page?

Comment: no browser is not in winform but my winform app turns on the browser n browse the page n takes snapshot of the page in any browser bt my app cant know wheather the page is loaded or not !!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand exactly what you're trying to do, but I'll take a stab at it: It sounds like you're trying to open whatever program is set as the user's default web browser, and then do something like a `BitBlt` to take a screenshot of it.

However, as you've noticed, it's difficult to just wait a pre-defined interval and *hope* the browser has completely loaded. Instead, **you could try something like `WaitForIdleInput` after running the process, which will suspend the thread's execution until the process has finished initializing and is idle (waiting for user input).** This should allow the browser to finish loading before you proceed with taking the snapshot.

Something like the following code:

```
//start the web browser
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe");

//wait for it to completely finish loading
proc.WaitForInputIdle();

//take your screenshot, or whatever
//...
```

Comment: Ya sir, It doesnot work cause they immediately turns on ideal state when process is start !!

Comment: You could try specifying a time in milliseconds to wait: `proc.WaitForInputIdle(3000);`

Comment: No that is not the case. Actually in my project (webfonts.com), I have made a windows appliation which will open the browser and inputs the URL and takes snapshot but i need to know wheather the page in an specific browser (like firefox,opera,ie etc) is loaded or not so that the snapshot can be taken. Even if internet is too slow my application should take the snapshot after that browser page loads, but my code cant know weather the page is loaded because its a windows application, what to do in this case ??????

Comment: That kind of automation macro is going to be extremely difficult to get right, for exactly the reasons you mentioned. I highly suggest trying to figure out another way to achieve the results that you want.

Comment: I am having an problem doing that !! actually in my site (www.webfonts.fonts.com) i should know my 10000 fonts. How do they appear in different browsers in different OS. So I am taking those snapshots. Is there any other solution rather than doing this ?? I would highly appreciate ur suggestion. Plz help me !!